# MATLAB 'Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.'

Tags: matlab, vector

```
x = 0:1:5; % define x array 
y = exp(x)+x.^4+2*x.^2-x+3; % define y array
dx = diff(x); % 1 1 1 1 1 dx has one number less than x 
dy = diff(y); % -5 -1 -3 -4 -2
slope = dy./dx
z=exp(x)+4*x.^3 +4*x-1
plot(x,slope,'*',x,z)
```

'Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.'

Been stuck on this for a while, I am not sure what to do. ive seen the other responses to the same error but can not understand the code. It seems its the colon : that might help but i am not sure how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that the vectors must be the same length.  `x` and `slope` do not have the same amount of elements. How are you supposed to plot them if there is not an x-y pair?

Answer (score 1):

Since `slope` is computed from *two* consecutive values, I suggest you take the average betwen consecutive points as the `x`-axis values for ´slope`:

```
plot((x(1:end-1)+x(2:end))/2,slope, '*',x,z)
```

[image]

Comment: ahhh thanks  a lot. I have another problem now, how would I plotting the differences between the two solutions on another graph? the x values dont have the same amount of values..

Comment: You could apply `interp1` to `x` and `y` to obtain the midway values, and then subtract